# M303 Autotune for heatbed fails with "Bad Extruder Number" error. Why?

Tags: pid, autotune, m303

I'm attempting to get Autotune PID values for the heatbed. I'm using `M303` with an `E-1` parameter to designate the bed.  I'm also using an `S` parameter to designate the desired temperature. It's returning a "Bad Extruder Number" error each time. `M303` with no `E` parameter correctly runs the Autotune process and returns valid P, I and D values for the Extruder heater.

I'm using instructions found here, [Marlin Firmware M301 / M303 / M304 G-Code Commands Explained](https://www.3dprintgorilla.com/marlin-firmware-m301-m303-m304-g-code-commands/).

Printer is a Prusa i3 clone using Marlin (version 1.1.6) with Repetier to send the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your Marlin version is pretty old.

To enable the tuning of the bed, the `configuration.h` file requires the following compiler directive to be set:

`#define PIDTEMPBED`

If the hotend is tuned instead, this means that either the directive has not been set, or that the firmware is flawed by the following [issue (#12468)](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/12468).

You should update the firmware to a newer version by flashing a more recent build. Note that the issue was present in a Marlin 2.0.x bugfix branch, so try the latest version or one from early 2019.